# Extract part of multipolygon that does not intersect with another geometry in Spatialite / QGIS DB manager

Tags: qgis, spatialite, virtual-layer

I have a point layer (with a buffer value), and a polygon layer (footprint) that intersects the point buffer.

Using only SQL in QGIS Virtual Layers (i.e. based on Spatialite), how can I get the difference between the point buffer (`buffer(pt.geometry,bufvalue)`) and footprint, *where the difference does not intersect with the point geometry*?

See the following image for an illustration - green is the footprint, orange pentagon is the point, orange polygon is the difference. I just want the ticked geometry.

[image]

The difference returns a multipolygon, and I only need one part. However, I can't split multipolygons into single polygons (there is no `ST_Dump()` equivalent in Spatialite [due to SQLite not handling array values](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spatialite-users/04YoENWokuA), apparently)

And I can't use the CLI/GUI commands (which separate multigeometries into 'elementary geometries') as I want to create a virtual layer in QGIS, so it has to be 100% in SQL.

How can I approach this problem using SQL in Virtual Layers only? (i.e. not using any other processing tools)

I am thinking I may have to loop over the number of geometries for multipolygons using recursive functions in place of `generate_series()`, and test if each one intersects with the point geometry...

Comment: SpatiaLite queries can be combined with QGIS expressions when creating the virtual layer. For example, to keep the indexed part as 1, the following clause can be used: `SELECT geometry_n(geometry,1) as geom FROM 'layer'`. Therefore, if you could know the index of the part to be extracted (even the parts should be able to be sorted with `order_parts()`) I think the problem would be reduced to how to implement the expressions in the query.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no way of directly knowing what the index of the part is to be extracted - each part has to be spatially tested (disjoint from point geometry). The issue is that I can't test each part separately without 'splitting' the multipolygon into single parts, which I can't do with Spatialite SQL. So I have resorted to my convoluted fallback of looping through each part (where `num_geometries(geometry) >1`) using a sequence of indices generated by a CTE in `geometry_n()`, then keeping the ones that don't intersect with the point geometry... then collecting those back... cripes.

Comment: Today I also wrote a query to dump geometries in a virtual layer, for the following question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/334371/measure-collected-polygons-in-geometry-generator-avoiding-extra-texts-from-mult . If you wanted to see it and give your opinion, the same if you wanted to write in an answer how you achieved your index sequence, I think it would be a good contribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to improve my query a bit, to dump single-part geometries in a virtual layer. I would appreciate if you can test it with your data:

```
WITH RECURSIVE parts AS (
  SELECT d.buffer_fid, d.poly_fid, d.total, 1 AS part
  FROM dump_me AS d
  UNION ALL
    SELECT d.buffer_fid, d.poly_fid, d.total, part + 1 AS part
    FROM dump_me AS d 
    INNER JOIN parts as p
      ON d.buffer_fid = p.buffer_fid AND d.poly_fid = p.poly_fid AND p.part < d.total
),
dump_me AS (
  SELECT buffer_fid, poly_fid, NumGeometries( geom) AS total
  FROM diff
),
diff AS (
  SELECT b.fid AS buffer_fid, p.fid AS poly_fid , ST_Difference( b.geom, p.geometry) AS geom
  FROM buffers AS b
  INNER JOIN polys AS p
    ON ST_Intersects( b.geom, p.geometry) = 1
),
buffers AS (
  SELECT fid, ST_Buffer( geometry, <bufvalue>) AS geom
  FROM points
),
dumped AS (
SELECT p.buffer_fid, p.poly_fid, p.part, GeometryN( d.geom, p.part) as geom
FROM parts AS p
INNER JOIN diff AS d
  ON p.buffer_fid = d.buffer_fid AND p.poly_fid = d.poly_fid
)
--SELECT * FROM buffers;
--SELECT * FROM diff;
--SELECT * FROM dump_me;
--SELECT * FROM parts;
--SELECT * FROM dumped;
-- to debug, comment on the following lines and uncomment the previous SELECT clause of your interest
SELECT d.buffer_fid, d.poly_fid, d.part, d.geom
FROM dumped AS d
INNER JOIN points AS p
 ON  d.buffer_fid = p.fid AND ST_Intersects( d.geom, p.geometry) = 0;
```

I am assuming the existence of a *points* layer and the existence of a *polys* layer, both with unique values for the *fid* field.

The same would appreciate the opinion of any SQL specialist to improve the query using tools available in SpatiaLite, in the virtual layers environment of QGIS.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel, excellent answer! This by and large worked - it is quite similar to the query I used except much cleaner :-) and I kept my recursive CTE to a hard limit of 5 in order to minimise processing (which works in my use case knowing the data). For anyone else bumbling their way through I realised after much trial and error that the recursive CTE must be at the top for it to work.

Comment: @she_weeds You are welcome. It was interesting for me to also understand how the recursive CTE works.